# What is the tamil character range in UTF-8?

Tags: python, string, utf-8, character-encoding, tamil

I am not a tamil speaker, however, for simple NLP applications I am developing, I have to detect whether characters in a python string (mixed with digits, punctuation, HTML tags) are tamil or not. If not, simply I have to remove the character. The concept is simple, but even after much searching, I am unable to find the tamil character range in UTF-8. Some help will be needed. Is it a continuous block of numbers such as 65 to 90 in ASCII capital letters? Or do I have to develop something more sophisticated to check each character?

Comment: What is your top Google hit for "tamil code block"?

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia on [Tamil script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_script):

> Unicode range: [U+0B80–U+0BFF](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0B80.pdf)